# Notion of fixed point for the sequence $x_{n+1}=f_n(x_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fixed-point-theorems

Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space and let $f_n:X\to X,\ n\in \mathbb{N}$ be a sequence of contractions.

> Is there any notion of fixed point for the following sequence? $$x_{n+1}=f_n(x_n),\ n\in \mathbb{N},\ x_1\in X$$

I know that when $f_n$ are all the same function $f$ $\ \forall n$, and $f$ is a contraction then by [Banach fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) the sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges to the unique fixed point of $f$. But I was unable to find a similar result for the present case. The idea that I have is that maybe we have to have some kind of *mutual contraction* relations between the different functions, i.e. we have to have some $L(m,n)\in (0,1),\ \forall n,m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(f_m(x),f_n(y))\le L(m,n) d(x,y)\ \forall x,y\in X,\ \forall m,n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Can anybody kindly provide any related literature or maybe some idea regarding analysis of this kind of sequence? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If all $f_n$ are constant, you have just a sequence of points, and unless $X$ is compact, that sequence need not even have accumulation points. You need some good relation between the $f_n$. If they converge (pointwise, but that implies locally uniform convergence by equiconituity) to some $f\colon X \to X$, that limit function is non-expanding ($d(f(x),f(y)) \leqslant d(x,y)$). If it is a contraction, the sequence $(x_n)$ converges to the fixed point of $f$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, but if $f_n$ is some constant contraction $f$, then doesn't the completeness of $X$ imply the existence of an accumulation point $x$ in $X$?

Comment: Also, it would be very kind of you if you can explain why if $f_n\to f$ and if $f$ is a contraction imply that the sequence $x_{n}$ converge to the fixed point of $f$.

Comment: Consider $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $f_n \colon x \mapsto n+1$. Then you have $x_n = n$, and no accumulation point. As for the other point, I may have been a little too optimistic, and we need a bit more to reach the conclusion, I'm not sure. If we have a contraction constant $c < 1$ that works for all $f_n$ (and hence also for $f$), that suffices. For large $n$, the fixed point of $f$ isn't moved much, and everything far away hence moves towards the fixed point. After a while, you are in a small enough ball around the fixed point that you have uniform convergence.

Comment: Oh, ok, I understand, though in the first example the $f_n$'s are dependent on $n$, I actually meant that $f_n$'s are all equal to some contraction $f$, irrespective of what $n$ is. I will try to think about the second observation you made to see if it leads me anywhere. Thanks for the comments! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I come up with a little bit technical condition. Basically, I specify the rate of convergence for $f_n\to f$.

I am lazy and assume $X$ is a closed subset of some Banach space (just for notation) and write the norm  as $|\cdot|$. Supremum norm for bounded functions from $X$ to $X$ is denoted by $\|\cdot\|$.

For $n\in\mathbb N$ let $e_{n} = \| f_{n+1} - f_{n} \|$.
Assume $\sum_{n=0}^\infty e_n < \infty$ and there is some $c < 1$ such $|f_n(y) - f_n(x)| \le c |y-x|$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$ and $x,y\in X$.

I will modify the usual proof of Banach fix point theorem and show that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence.
For large $n$ notice that
\begin{align} 
|x_{n+1} - x_n| 
&= |f_n(x_n) - f_{n-1}(x_{n-1})| \\
&= |f_n(x_n) - f_{n-1}(x_{n}) + f_{n-1}(x_{n}) - f_{n-1}(x_{n-1})| \\
&\le e_{n-1} + c |x_n - x_{n-1}| \\
&\le e_{n-1} + c e_{n-2} + c^2 |x_{n-1} - x_{n-2}| \\
&\le \underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} c^k e_{n-1-k}}_{=:\eta_{n-1}} + c^n |x_{1} - x_{0}| \\
\end{align}
Thus, for $m\ge 1$ we have
\begin{align} 
|x_{n+m} - x_n| 
&\le |x_{n+m} - x_{n+m-1}| + \dotsb + |x_{n+1} - x_n| \\
&\le \eta_{n+m-2} + c^{n+m-1} |x_1 - x_0| + \dotsb + \eta_{n-1} + c^n |x_1 - x_0| \\
&= \underbrace{\sum_{k=n-1}^{n+m-2} \eta_{k}}_{(*)} + |x_1 - x_0| \underbrace{\sum_{k=n}^{n+m-1} c^{k}}_{(**)}.
\end{align}
As $\eta_{n-1}$ is a summand of a Cauchy product, the sum $(*)$ converges to $0$ for $n\to\infty$. The sum $(**)$ also converges to $0$, as geometric series converges.
Thus, $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence and has a limit, which is a fix point of $f$.

Comment: I have had same kind of idea, though I wanted to see if it is possible to find a condition amongst $f_n$, maybe without convergence to some $f$, which allows us to have this kind of Cauchy sequence. Can we generalize this analysis to that case also?

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay hm hard to say. what are your $f_n$'s? is there some kind of structure?

Comment: It is actually difficult to describe the $f_n$'s but lets say we know that $$\|f_n-f_m\|\le A$$ for some $A$.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay: That's not much. Like in .@DanielFischer's example, you can always consider some constant function $f_n$. Then, the convergence of $x_n$ is the same like $f_n$. So  $f_n$ need to converge, but not necessarily at the rate I demand.